# Update objects in RealmSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, updates

I know that lot's of similar questions are around - I fear that my problem is on such basic level, that all the other question I could find, are much more complicated and yet, doesn't quite seem to answer this.

I'm implementing 'Settings' in my diary app - and I need to let the user be able to edit (amongst other things) the name of the diary.

To understand my issue: For starters in the app, you have a tableView with all current diaries - then when you enter a specific diary, this is where you find 'Settings' to edit this specific diary.

In here, when clicking a tableViewCell named "Diary Name", you enter a simple viewController with a textField (holding you current diary name) and a button that will pop you back and change the diary name to the new input in this textField.

Here's my current code on this 'save-button':

```
@IBAction func saveChanges(_ sender: Any) {
let newDiaryName = Diaries() // Here, I need to reach the specific diary that we are currently editing!
diary?.diaryName = changeDiaryNameTextField.text!

let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(newDiaryName)
    }
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
}
```

So I'm sorry, but I'm new in this world...

My question is: How in hell do I reach the specific diary, that I'm in at this point? - And is this function even the right one to use, when wanting to update an object?

Back in the first tableView with the list of all the Diaries, I've saved the diaries like this:

(So I guess one diary is something like allDiaries[indexPath].. But how do I reach that from this whole other viewController?)

```
let allDiaries: Results<Diaries>

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    allDiaries = realm.objects(Diaries.self).sorted(byKeyPath: String("dateCreated"), ascending: false)
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Sorry about the long explanation, I didn't know how to ask otherwise!

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not attach images, the code is the correct one.

Comment: Just unwrap :) click on the red circle and xcode will suggest you :)

Comment: Force unwrapping silences the warnings again, but the app still crashes. Sorry, I'll take the photo down again.

Comment: Provide code please, also if it is possible what is the error message when the app crashes

Comment: Well, both when I force unwrap like this: 'realm.add(newDiaryName!)' & when I do it like this: 'let newDiaryName = diary!', I get the error 'Thread 1: signal SIGABRT'

Comment: There should be the reason, either upload project somewhere so I can run locally, or you should find the reason

Comment: This line `diary?.diaryName = changeDiaryNameTextField.text!` is not valid if diary is an `Realm Object` that was retreived from the database. It would crash.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your `Dairy` view controller where you save name is DairyViewControll, and you open it from DairiesViewController.
As I don't know you present it or push(Storyboard segue) I'll show both cases.

The main idea is to assign your dairy object before present.

```
class DairiesViewController: UIViewController {

    //open selected dairy, the first option if you present it, second via segue
```

> `1. present`

```
    func openDairy(diary: Dairy) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil) //please make sure your storyboard is "main" otherwise change name
        let dairyVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dairyIdentifier") as! DairyViewControll
        dairyVC.dairy = dairy
        self.present(dairyVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

> `2. via segue`

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     let dairyVC = segue.destination as! DairyViewControll
     dairyVC.dairy = self.dairy // holds selected dairy
 }

class DairyViewControll: UIViewController {
    let dairy: Dairy! // the dairy user selects to edit
    @IBAction func saveChanges(_ sender: Any) {
        // you save method is here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! I'm actually pushing it - but the concept is the same. I'm using version 1 - and I'm already doing that. The problem is, that when I try to reach the new variable, that I created, I get the error: " Value of optional type 'Diaries?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Diaries' "  I can post a photo of the whole class with this error shown, if you would like?

Comment: I posted a photo, showing what happened when I tried, what you also said in version 1 :)